# resume Rsnapshot to same drive

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

Sometimes, on a large rsync using Rsnapshot, the NFS mount we are syncing to will drop.

Then when you run:

```
rnsapshot monthly
```

to resume it, it will behave as if this is a brand new, rotating the `monthly.0` to `monthly.1` and so on.

Is there a way to resume the `rsync` using `rsnapshot monthly` if something gets interrupted? That won't start a brand new backup?

Comment: So in your setup your syncing some local drive data to an NFS mount? If so, this is not related to your question, but you will get much better performance if you run rsnapshot on the remote end if that is possible for you.

Comment: I wish I could, it's just a storage mount running an nfs server. Its a paid service.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *no not really but sort of*. rsnapshot runs as a batch job - generally triggered from a cron job. It does not keep any state between runs apart from the backups themselves. If your NFS mount goes away mid backup, after a while you'll get some sort of IO error, and rsnapshot will give up and die with an error. The backup will fail. Next time it is run after the failure, it will start the backup as if from scratch.

However, if you use the `sync_first` config option, and *not* the `link_dest` option, rsnapshot will do a better job of recovery. It will leave the files its already transferred in place and won't have to transfer them again, but it will have to check again that the source and destination are the same in the usual `rsync` way. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsnapshot) gives some detail on this.

This is not the case with the `link_dest` method which for most errors removes the work its done and starts again. Specifically, on error `link_dest` does a "rollback" like this:

```
ERROR: /usr/bin/rsync returned 255 while processing sam@localhost:..
WARNING: Rolling back "localhost/"
/bin/rm -rf /tmp/rs-test/backups/hourly.0/localhost/
/bin/cp -al /tmp/rs-test/backups/hourly.1/localhost \
    /tmp/rs-test/backups/hourly.0/localhost
touch /tmp/rs-test/backups/hourly.0/
rm -f /tmp/rs-test/rsnapshot-test.lock
```

If your not using it already, and you can use it (apparently some non UNIX systems can't), use the `sync_first` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use rsnapshot, but I've written my own equivalent wrapper over rsync [in perl] and I do delta backups, so I've encountered similar problems.

To solve the problem of creating "false whole backups", the basic idea is to do:

```
while 1
    rsnapshot remote_whatever/tmp

    if (rsnapshot_was_okay) then
        mv remote_whatever/tmp remote_whatever/monthly_whatever
        break
    endif
end
```

The above `mv` should be atomic, even over NFS.

I just answered a similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/741346/rsync-directory-so-all-changes-appear-atomically/741420#741420 that has more details